# Problem while downloading .apk file from https web server in Android

Tags: android

I have a webserver on which I am putting my .apk file.I have given 
correct mime type also for apache web server. 
 When I am trying to download from HTTP then it is working fine but 
the same thing is not getting downloaded from HTTPS site. 
I have a verisign test certificate which is valid for one month for HTTPS. 
Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Regards 
Dileep

Comment: What is the error you are getting from log cat? Or is it returning a bad response?

Comment: Not getting any error in Logcat.Only download is not getting started from https website.

Comment: Is [this](http://androidforums.com/droid-x-all-things-root/210150-issue-installing-apk-files.html) related to the issue at all?

Comment: I am getting the same problem for HTTPS site....Did u find any solution yet ?